# error insert data into mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, insert

Can someone help me, i get this error. what is wrong?

> ERROR:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''", "$_POST[''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\community\addgame.php on
>   line 46

Here is the code:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>The Game Community</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Add a Game</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <form action="addgame.php" method="post">
                    <p>
                        <label for="navn">Name: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="field">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="e-post">Release year: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="release" class="field">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="telefon">Publisher: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="publisher" class="field">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="adresse">Genre: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="genre" class="field">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Add Game">
                    </p>

                    <?php
                        $dbhost = 'localhost';
                        $dbuser = 'root';
                        $dbpass = '';
                        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
                        if(! $conn )
                        {
                          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                        }
                        $sql = 'INSERT INTO gamelist '.
                               '(ID, name, release, publisher, genre)'.
                               'VALUES ("''", "$_POST['name']", "$_POST['release']", "$_POST['publisher']", "$_POST['genre']")';

                        mysql_select_db('games');
                        $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
                        if(! $retval )
                        {
                          die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
                        }
                        echo "Entered data successfully\n";
                        mysql_close($conn);
                    ?>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: what is this ? `'VALUES ("''",` no connector(.) then why '""'

Comment: Does the colours about show you that you need to escape the '

Comment: @JakeGould That's why I asked, as I smelled error there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query which is failing:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO gamelist '.
       '(ID, name, release, publisher, genre)'.
       'VALUES ("''", "$_POST['name']", "$_POST['release']", "$_POST['publisher']", "$_POST['genre']")';
```

Your query is a mix of single quotes & double quotes. But single quotes (`'`) don’t handle string substitution. So change it to this using double quotes for the string and periods (`.`) for the string concatenation:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO gamelist"
     . " (ID, name, release, publisher, genre)"
     . " VALUES ('', '" . $_POST['name'] . '", "' . $_POST['release'] . '", "' . $_POST['publisher'] . '", "' . $_POST['genre'] . '")'
     ;
```

I also formatted it so the spaces () and periods (`.`) between lines happen on the left side of values for readability. When you place it to the right the values like your original query, it technically works the same but the chances of stuff not being viewable on the right side of the screen are high. So you might inadvertently miss something. Better put that stuff to to left so you know exactly what is happening at all times.

Comment: thanks, but now i gpt this error messages..

Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\community\addgame.php on line 39

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\community\addgame.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: release in C:\wamp\www\community\addgame.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: publisher in C:\wamp\www\community\addgame.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: genre in C:\wamp\www\community\addgame.php on line 46